# Can Chez scheme produce compiled binaries?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme, chez-scheme

I have been using chicken scheme lately and i find it really good, someone suggested that chez scheme is the fastest scheme implementation. So i wanted to try it, but i am not sure how to create compiled binaries from chez like in chicken scheme.

Answer (score 11):

As Sylwester has already mentioned the fasl binaries, but this solution still requires to distribute a chez scheme interpreter. A more interesting solution which produces distributable binary is chez-exe https://github.com/gwatt/chez-exe

Comment: Any benefit in terms of executable size and speed when comparing with Chicken?

Comment: @antonio Yes Chez scheme is actually faster than Chicken. Though I absolutely love chicken, I have heard a lot about chez which is why I wanted to give it a full inspection before making a final opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Chez has a JIT and you can compile files into fasl-like files that you can run just like source files.

From [Using Chez Scheme](https://www.scheme.com/csug8/use.html):

> Chez Scheme compiles source forms as it sees them to machine code
>   before evaluating them, i.e., "just in time." In order to speed
>   loading of a large file or group of files, each file can be compiled
>   ahead of time via compile-file, which puts the compiled code into a
>   separate object file. For example, (compile-file "path") compiles the
>   forms in the file path.ss and places the resulting object code in the
>   file path.so. Loading a pre-compiled file is essentially no different
>   from loading the source file, except that loading is faster since
>   compilation has already been done.
>
> When compiling a file or set of files, it is often more convenient to
>   use a shell command than to enter Chez Scheme interactively to perform
>   the compilation. This is easily accomplished by "piping" in the
>   command to compile the file as shown below.
>
> ```
> echo '(compile-file "filename")' | scheme -q
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but i was looking for a compiled single binary which does not require a chez-scheme interpreter. Found an interesting solution https://github.com/gwatt/chez-exe check it out.